# How to execute all statements synchronously in a method in windows service c#

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2013, outlook, windows-services

I want to execute all statements synchronously in a windwos service in whichever methods they are.

I'm creating an instance of outlook using c#. But outlook is not even being opened and all other statements after that are executed. Ultimately I'm not getting output as expected. Waiting for all sort of response. Thanks in advance

Here is my code.

```
public static void SendMail(DataRow dr)
{
            // Create the Outlook application.

            Outlook.Application oApp = oApp = new Outlook.Application();
            // Create a new mail item.
            Outlook.MailItem oMsg = (Outlook.MailItem)oApp.CreateItem(Outlook.OlItemType.olMailItem);

            int iAttachType = (int)Outlook.OlAttachmentType.olEmbeddeditem;
            oMsg.BodyFormat = Outlook.OlBodyFormat.olFormatHTML;
            oMsg.HTMLBody = String.Format("<html><body><table align='center'><tr><td><img src="+"cid:{0}"+"</body></html></td></tr></table>",img);
            Outlook.Recipient oRecip = (Outlook.Recipient)oRecips.Add(dr["EmpEmailAddr"].ToString());
            oRecip.Resolve();
            // Send.
            oMsg.Send();
}
```

This code snippet is only a part of the method. A whole lot more processing is also done like calling other methods and processes in this method. This method should send a mail on receipents address with an attachment.

Before opening the outlook in the method all other processing is done. So mail is not sent. If I debug the same method then all statements are executed one by one. so in that case mail is sent. Please help me with this. Thank you

Comment: Why do you need to open Outlook to send an email? Just use the SMTP to send emails.

Comment: whoever downvoted it please upvote. Because I've tried SMTP. And It's not working as expected. I need user intercation application for this.

Answer (score 0):

Any user interaction tool doesn't go well with Windows Service. There is an option "Allow Service to Interact with Desktop" that you need to check while installing the window service for these kind of automations.

Why do you really need to open Outlook to send an email? Just use the SMTP to send emails.

`System.Net.Mail.MailMessage message = new System.Net.Mail.MailMessage();
message.To.Add("luckyperson@online.microsoft.com");
message.Subject = "This is the Subject line";
message.From = new System.Net.Mail.MailAddress("From@online.microsoft.com");
message.Body = "This is the message body";
System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient smtp = new System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient("yoursmtphost");
smtp.Send(message);`

Comment: I've tried smtp but it doesn't work well with exchange server. If you've any solution for it I would love to hear that. Thank you

Comment: have you tried "Allow Service to Interact with Desktop"? and you may have Thread.Sleep after each operation as needed.

Comment: I can use Thread.Sleep but I don't any unexpected delay between statement executions. Next statement should get executed as soon as the previous one is completed.

Answer (score 0):

**Microsoft does not currently recommend, and does not support, Automation of Microsoft Office applications from any unattended, non-interactive client application or component (including ASP, ASP.NET, DCOM, and NT Services), because Office may exhibit unstable behavior and/or deadlock when Office is run in this environment.**

If you are building a solution that runs in a server-side context, you should try to use components that have been made safe for unattended execution. Or, you should try to find alternatives that allow at least part of the code to run client-side. If you use an Office application from a server-side solution, the application will lack many of the necessary capabilities to run successfully. Additionally, you will be taking risks with the stability of your overall solution. Read more about that in the [Considerations for server-side Automation of Office](https://support.microsoft.com/en-nz/kb/257757?wa=wsignin1.0) article.

As a workaround you may use third-party components or just BCL classes such as System.Net.Mail.MailMessage.